# Create sliding left effect using Vuejs animation

Tags: vue.js

I've read [this official](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html) document about Vuejs animation. But using it css hooks, I can only make element appear/disappear with fade and different duration.

```
<div id="demo">
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">
    Toggle
  </button>
  <transition name="fade">
    <p v-if="show">hello</p>
  </transition>
</div>


.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active in <2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0
}
```

How to use Vuejs Animation to create a sliding effect? Like the one [here](http://www.jssor.com/demos/full-width-slider.slider).  Is it possible? Please provide some sample code.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can absolutely do this with VueJS.
Have a look at the example under. You can see two examples, one is the adopted code for your case(to make it slide). And other is a simple image slider, that loops through array of images in 3 seconds interval.

Important thing to note here, is that we wrap the image element in for loop to force the element to be destroyed, because otherwise your elements will not be removed from DOM and will not transition (virtual DOM).

For better understanding of transitions in VueJS in recommend you to check out [getting started guide - transition section](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    message: 'Click for slide',
    show: true,
    imgList: [
        'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
      'http://via.placeholder.com/350x151',
      'http://via.placeholder.com/350x152'
    ],
    currentImg: 0
  },
  mounted() {
    setInterval(() => {
        this.currentImg = this.currentImg + 1;
    }, 3000);
  }
})
```

```css
#demo {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-leave-active,
.slide-enter-active {
  transition: 1s;
}
.slide-enter {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}
.slide-leave-to {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.img-slider{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

.img-slider img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>VueJS 2.0 - image slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="demo">
      <button v-on:click="show = !show">
        Toggle
      </button>
      <transition name="slide">
        <p v-if="show">{{message}}</p>
      </transition>
      <h3>
        Img slider
      </h3>
      <transition-group tag="div" class="img-slider" name="slide">
      <div v-for="number in [currentImg]" v-bind:key="number" >
        <img :src="imgList[Math.abs(currentImg) % imgList.length]"/>
      </div>
      </transition-group>
     </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey, great example here, thanks for this! Got a question, this only slides in one direction, how do I allow for example two arrows one left and one right which slide the images to either right or left???

Comment: @sicky I am currently stuck in a similar issue my Vue transitions are not triggering, however, my data seems to be reactive. It would be great if you could have a look at it and share your thoughts as to where am I going wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022673/vue-transition-not-triggering-on-button-click

Comment: I'm with @Benny How do we slide to the other side?

Comment: I started using vue-slick instead of fiddling around with vue-js animations to do a simple slide effect, it also has support for many other effects for sliding. 
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: @Benny I think you could use methods with body like `this.currentImg = this.currentImg + 1` as left button and `this.currentImg =  this.currentImg - 1`as next button

Comment: this seems not working in Vue 3. not sure what's happened: https://codepen.io/dhika345/pen/QWZbamg

Answer (score 14):

Thanks for the answer above it helped me a lot!
Since the original example had buttons to slide in both directions,
I improved it somewhat by adding "Next" and "Previous" buttons. I swap the animation to have it go the oposite way when pressing "Previous":

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    back: false,
    currentIndex: 0
  },
  methods: {
    next(){
      this.back = false;
      this.currentIndex++;
    },
    prev(){
      this.back = true;
      this.currentIndex--;
    }
  },
})
```

```css
#demo {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-leave-active,
.slide-enter-active {
  transition: 1s;
}
.slide-enter {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}
.slide-leave-to {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.slideback-leave-active,
.slideback-enter-active {
  transition: 1s;
}
.slideback-enter {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
.slideback-leave-to {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}

.div-slider{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
}

.div-slider .card {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #60adff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>VueJS 2.0 - image slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="demo">
      
      <h3>
        div slider
      </h3>
      <transition-group tag="div" class="div-slider" :name="back? 'slideback' : 'slide'">
       <div v-if="currentIndex === 0" key="1">
        <div class="card">
          DIV 1
        </div>
       </div>
       <div v-if="currentIndex === 1" key="2" >
        <div class="card">
          DIV 2
        </div>
       </div>
       <div v-if="currentIndex === 2" key="3" >
        <div class="card">
          DIV 1
        </div>
       </div>
      </transition-group>
      <button @click="prev()" >prev</button>
      <button @click="next()">next</button>
     </div>
     
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Simple and efficient!

Comment: This doesn't work, even in the code snippet. Consider fixing or removing this answer.

Comment: this seems not working in Vue 3. not sure what's happened: https://codepen.io/dhika345/pen/gOBpooa

Comment: @mending3 in Vue3 the name of the classes applied for enter / leave transitions changed! Check [the doc page](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition.html#css-based-transitions)