# How to make custom carousel animation with vue?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I am developing Vue app with [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/) and I need a carousel on it. Carousel should be made without any carousel library (because it is have lots of features which are not supported by libraries).
The carousel is work, but the slide animation doesn't. I have to slide elements which are wrapped by component `Slide`.
Here is code snippet from my `Carousel` component

```
<template>
    <transition-group
      class="slider"
      name="slide"
      tag="div"
    >
      // please don't pay attention on dataForSlider, it is just an array of objects with some data
      <div v-for="(slide, index) in dataForSlider" :key="index">
        <Slide
          v-if="currentPage === index"
          class="custom-slide"
          v-touch:swipe.left="swipeLeft"
          v-touch:swipe.right="swipeRight"
          :slide="slide"
          :activeSlide="index === currentPage"
          :index="index"
        >
//below components which are passed as a slot to the Slide component
          <Template1 v-if="slide.template === 'temp1' && currentPage === index" :slide="slide" :activeSlide="currentPage === index" :index="index"/>
          <Template2 v-else-if="slide.template === 'temp2' && currentPage === index" :slide="slide" :activeSlide="currentPage === index" :index="index"/>
          <Template3 v-else-if="slide.template === 'temp3' && currentPage === index" :slide="slide" :activeSlide="currentPage === index" :index="index"/>
          <Template4 v-else-if="slide.template === 'temp4' && currentPage === index" :slide="slide" :activeSlide="currentPage === index" :index="index"/>
          <Template5 v-else-if="slide.template === 'temp5' && currentPage === index" :slide="slide" :activeSlide="currentPage === index" :index="index"/>
          <Template6 v-else-if="slide.template === 'temp6' && currentPage === index" :slide="slide" :activeSlide="currentPage === index" :index="index"/>
          <Template7 v-else-if="slide.template === 'temp7' && currentPage === index" :slide="slide" :activeSlide="currentPage === index" :index="index"/>
          <Template8 v-else-if="slide.template === 'temp8' && currentPage === index" :slide="slide" :activeSlide="currentPage === index" :index="index"/>
        </Slide>
      </div>
    </transition-group>
</template>
<script>
import Slide from 'components/Slide'

import Template1 from 'components/slide-templates/Template1'
import Template2 from 'components/slide-templates/Template2'
import Template3 from 'components/slide-templates/Template3'
import Template4 from 'components/slide-templates/Template4'
import Template5 from 'components/slide-templates/Template5'
import Template6 from 'components/slide-templates/Template6'
import Template7 from 'components/slide-templates/Template7'
import Template8 from 'components/slide-templates/Template8'
export default {
  name: 'Carousel',
  components: {
    Slide,
    Template1,
    Template2,
    Template3,
    Template4,
    Template5,
    Template6,
    Template7,
    Template8
  },
  data () {
    return {
      currentPage: 0,
    }
  }
  methods: {
    swipeLeft () {
      this.currentPage = this.currentPage + 1
    },
    swipeRight () {
      this.currentPage = this.currentPage - 1
    }
  },
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
.custom-slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  >div {
    height: 100%;
  }
}
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-leave-active,
.slide-enter-active {
  transition: 1s;
}
.slide-enter {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}
.slide-leave-to {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
</style>
```

My problem is that I can change the slides, but I can't make it slides with smooth animation, it only change element rapidly without scrolling from right to left. Can someone say where is problem? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modify your stylings to have opacity and see if that looks smooth

```
.slide-leave-active,
.slide-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.slide-enter {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
  opacity: 0;
}
.slide-leave-to {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: the same result

Comment: check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42866098/create-sliding-left-effect-using-vuejs-animation

Comment: I saw this, but this doesn't work with div's, only images... my animation is the same

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do the transition on the transform? I think you have to specify it:

```
.slide-leave-active,
.slide-enter-active {
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}
```